# How do I restrict access to some actions in MVC5?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am developing a ASP.NET MVC5 project, with MySQL (More like MariaDB, actually) as the database and EF 6. 
I decided *not* to use the "native" authentication method as it used SQL Server, so... Well. there are a few issues I need to solve.

Say there is a controller called "Persons" with the default EF's CRUDE. Thing is, I want the default *logged-in* users to access the Details and List Views, but not the Create, Delete and Edit ones. So, according to a few answers in SO, I came up with the "solution" :

Create an abstract class inheriting the `Controller` class, and defining an overriding method at `OnActionExecuting`:

```cs
public abstract class InternalAreaBaseController: Controller {
    protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {

        if ( Session["UserObj"] == null ) {
            Response.Redirect( @"~\AcessoNegado\Desconectado" );
        }
        else{
            base.OnActionExecuting( filterContext );
        }

    }
}
```

I did the inheritance needed in `public class PersonsController : InternalAreaBaseController` ,and it works:
If the current session does not contain the "UserObj" object, which basically detects whether the user is connected or not, redirects to the "Disconnected" error page.

However, this only checks whether the user is connected; Inside `PersonsController`, there is the action   `public ActionResult Index()` which can be accessed by all the users, but there is also the action `public ActionResult Create()` which can only be accessed by users within a determined condition.

Is there a way of passing a flag alongside the `PersonController:InternalAreaBaseController` so the abstract class knows when to block determined users?

Something like

```
public abstract class InternalAreaBaseController: Controller {
public int AccessDegree { get;  set; }
public User? SessionData = Session["UserObj"];
protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{

       if ( SessionData == null ) {
           Response.Redirect( @"~\AcessoNegado\Desconectado" );
       }
       elseif(SessionData.AccessDegree<AccessDegree){
            Response.Redirect( @"~\AcessoNegado\SemCredenciais" ); //NotEnoughCredentials
       }
       else{
           base.OnActionExecuting( filterContext );
       }

    }
}
```

Comment: you can override the authentication provider to use whatever you like

Comment: What @Alex said; it's *much* easier to do that than to build an entire authentication/authorization system yourself.

Comment: @Alex, do you mean overrinding the OnAuthentication method?

Comment: By "'native' authentication", I'm assuming you mean ASP.NET Identity. There's nothing in Identity that explicitly cares what database system you use. Heck, actually I don't think there's anything in any version of ASP.NET authentication that dictates a particular database system. Identity, in particular, though, relies entirely on your subclas of `IdentityDbContext` and will use whatever database it uses. So, assuming you've got a proper connection to your database of choice, it should just work.

Comment: Chris, when you create a new MVC project in VS2013, you have the option of changing the authentication method, where it states (if the "Individual User Accounts" is chosen) that the SQL Server is used to store the users' profiles. http://www.asp.net/visual-studio/overview/2013/creating-web-projects-in-visual-studio#auth

Comment: Also, I tried it: it really creates an entire database in my Local SQL Server, given a connection string or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this way.

```
public ActionResult Login()
{
   bool IsValidUser = // Check User Credential
   if(IsValidUser) // If it is valid
   {
      FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie("username", false);
      return RedirectToAction("Index");
   }
   else
   {
      //Show the message "Invalid username or password"
   }
```

}

In the controller,

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult Index()
{
   // Do something
}
```

Comment: Yes, that would be fine... but I have _many_ controllers with _many_ actions within, and I was searching for a way to implement it with the least of repetitive code possible.

Comment: You can put [Authorize] on top of those controllers instead of putting it on top of each actions.

Comment: You could also create a single BaseController which would have the 'Authorize' attribute on it. Then all classes inheriting from the BaseController would be protected.